# How do I autocomplete search for usernames from database without using jQuery?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I've seen multiple exams for autocomplete using jQuery.

I've a list of usernames stored in my MySQL database. When the user types his username, I need to autocomplete from the data in the database with use of PHP, mySQL and AJAX (without use of jQuery). How do I do it?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch()` if you only need modern browsers

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=autocomplete+ajax+php+-jquery

Comment: @RaymondNijland I need to do without jquery. All google results include jQuery

Comment: @cyberdon I see from your comment that you didn't even click my google search link.. thats why i search with `-jquery` to exclude jquery from the Google results good luck..

Comment: I did not mean your search result. On googling normally, i meant. But I need mysql into the picture

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is mostly just a wrapper, to make commonly used JavaScript expressions easier. However, there is no magic functionality to it, you can - without any problem - use plain JavaScript.

Basically if you want to do it completely server sided (without any JS) you would get a rather bad user experience as a result of the database fetching.

The basic idea is that the client sends a request to the server, which in turn answers with a list of possible results and either lets the js locally adapt the view (the suggestions) or pushes the updated view directly to the client (not smooth).

Comment: The J in AJAX is for JavaScript

Comment: @Strawberry, true, well the question makes not that much sens IMO, that's why I thought he would maybe want to achieve something like no JS at all.